# Xamarin Forms iOS wrong Task icon

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I think a have a really simple problem but I am not quite sure if I am doing something wrong or if this is a Xamarin issue.

I have an iOS Xamarin Forms project where I am unable to set the "task" icon which is shown in the "tasks" view when pressing twice the home button.

It shows always the xamarin icon. For all the other icons like launch icon the correct icon is shown.
I don't find any xamarin icon in my project. I have all the icons in Assets.xcassets for App Icon set.

[image: Task View]

Which icon should should change the "task" icon. Is this set at a different place?
What is the name for this icon?

Any help is appreciated.

Used Environment:

- Visual Studio for Mac 8.5.6
- Xamarin.iOS 13.16.0.13
- Deployment Target iOS 13
- Xamarin.Forms 4.6.8

**Update**

I meanwhile updated the development environment:

- Visual Studio for Mac 8.6
- Xamarin.iOS 13.18

The result is still the same:
[image: Task View with Favorite Bar]
[image: AppIcon]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was probably an issue with my environment/visual studio as it also occured with a new project.

I switch a few times between deploying different apps in release and debug mode and now it is working with the same code as before.

Seems like a chased a phantom for to many hours.

Comment: In my case phone restart helped :)